# TypeError running Python with mysql.connector in terminal

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to run the following python-sql connection program, that's supposed to let you change the discount of a product:

```py
    import mysql.connector
    
    product= input("Choose product: ")
    mycursor=mydb.cursor()
    
    mycursor.execute("select P_discount from Product where P_name='"+product+"'")
    myDiscount = mycursor.fetchall()
    
    if (myDiscount[0] == None or myDiscount[0]==0):
        print("No discount right now")
    else:
        print("The discount is: "+ str(myDiscount[0]))
    
    
    
    question=input("Do want change the discount (y for yes, n for no): ")
    if (question=="y" or question=="Y"):
        newDiscount=input("Choose the new discount: ")
        mycursor.execute=("Update Product set P_discount='"+newDiscount+"' where P_name='"+product+"'")
        mydb.commit()
        mycursor.execute("select P_discount from Product where P_name='"+product+"'")
        productNewDiscount=mycursor.fetchall()
        print("New discount: " + str(productNewDiscount)+" $")
    
    mydb.close()
```

And when i do, I get the following error:

```
 File "DBApp.py", line 31, in <module>
mycursor.execute("select P_discount from Product where P_name='"+product+"'")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

As you can see in the code, I run the mycursor.execute() above and don't get the error.

Comment: `mycursor.execute=("Update Product set P_discount='"+newDiscount+"' where P_name='"+product+"'")` this line is assigning `mycursor.execute` to a `str`.  It should be `mycursor.execute("Update Product set P_discount='"+newDiscount+"' where P_name='"+product+"'")` (no "=")

Comment: Please read about and use parameterized queries instead of concatenating strings to create sql statements (https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-parameterized-query-using-prepared-statement/)